# RadioButtonList 1 Row Coloured

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, radiobuttonlist, itemdatabound

Please Help.

I am using ASP/ VB.net and I have a radio button populated from the database in the code behind like this.

```
rdoTheTest.DataSource = Test.Test_Get()
rdoTheTest.DataBind()
```

I now get the radio list on the screen and I want to colour 1 row, when I use this they all go the same colour.

```
rdoTheTest.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
```

In the past when using a listview scenario I could do something like this;

```
Private Sub LvTheTest_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles lvTheTest.ItemDataBound
    Dim SomeTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("SomeTextBox"), TextBox)
    If DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "SomeDBVAR") = 1 Then SomeTextBox.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
End Sub
```

My Intention was to do this;

```
Private Sub rdoTheTest_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rdoTheTest.DataBinding
    If DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "SomeDBVAR") = 1 Then sender.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
End Sub
```

Problem is only 1 row is retrieved in DataBinding when there is 10 rows and when using ListView I get 10 rows because you can use Handles ItemDataBound you can manipulate on every row pull.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always color the specific radio *after* the data have been bound using `OnDataBound`, for example:

```
Protected Sub rdoTheTest_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    rdoTheTest.Items.FindByValue("SomeDBVar").Attributes.Add("style", "color: red")
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Iterate bound list items and set the appropriate color based on the item value (or text):

```
    For Each item As ListItem In rdoTheTest.Items
        If item.Value = "1" Then
            item.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red")
        Else If item.Value = "2" Then
            item.Attributes.Add("style", "color: orange")
        Else 
            item.Attributes.Add("style", "color: green")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Your answer works in the exception me selected one entry. I should have explained a bit more, my bad. I have 10 rows in the database with high,medium,low priority being 1,2,3. So when it sees priority 1 then should be red,2 orange, 3 green. How can I do that?

Comment: @Kiel Updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: First off Thankyou, Dpant for taking your time to answer. I am so close to what I want, that works if the value in the radio button list is being used in the IF statement. My data source consists of ID,Desc,PriorityID. ID,Desc are assigned to the RadioButtonList. PriorityID column cant be called in the above statement. You can only assign 2 fields. Any ideas.

Comment: @Kiel In this case, the `RadioButtonList` control is not going to work for you, I am afraid. You can always use a templated control such as the `ListView` or build your radio buttons and add them to the page dynamically.

Comment: Yes I thought that when I starting using the RadioButtonList. I have now built a ListView with as many values from the DB as I need. I used sessions to implement selections made it go bold when it selected. I got it working brilliant. Thanks for your help though.